# Dev branch and end of sprint

Tags: version-control, branch, featuretoggle

We are 3 developers working on the same project and currently we have a branch each that we merge together when we all are done.
We would like to start using branches like dev/main/release so we all do our work in the same dev branch.

At the end of a sprint two of us are done but the third needs more time to finish his task, how do we handle the thirds code?

Make sure his unfinished code does not interfere with the rest and publish ghost code?
Cancel the release so he gets an extra sprint?

Comment: [Feature toggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle)

Comment: Great, thanks, seems to be a good way to go!